# Resources not releasing with UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

Here is how my two views are laid out:

[image]

Essentially my goal is to have `VC2` start 'fresh' every time, with everything new, including a `MPMusicPlayerController`.  I was under the impression that an `unwindsegue` removed the instance of the new view as well as it's resources but the music player is not being stopped. 
Before `VC2` ends, it runs a function that deregisters all the media player notifications and sets the music player itself = nil.  However I can still hear the music playing when it returns back to `VC1` and when I create a new instance of `VC2` my 'new' music player controller doesn't work (no notifications are registered).

Some code:

Music player is instantiated (`VC2`):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    [self registerMediaPlayerNotifications];
}
```

Register notifications:

```
- (void) registerMediaPlayerNotifications
{
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [notificationCenter addObserver: self
                           selector: @selector (handle_NowPlayingItemChanged:)
                               name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                             object: musicPlayer];

    [notificationCenter addObserver: self
                           selector: @selector (handle_PlaybackStateChanged:)
                               name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                             object: musicPlayer];

    [notificationCenter addObserver: self
                           selector: @selector (handle_VolumeChanged:)
                               name: MPMusicPlayerControllerVolumeDidChangeNotification
                             object: musicPlayer];

    [musicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
}
```

Snippet from `getNextSong`

```
   MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:test forProperty:MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID];
    MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [query addFilterPredicate: predicate];
    NSArray *queryResults = [query items];
    for (MPMediaItem *song in queryResults) {
        [musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:query];
        [musicPlayer play];
    }
```

Code that is executed before `VC2` is 'unwound':

```
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                                                  object: musicPlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                                  object: musicPlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: MPMusicPlayerControllerVolumeDidChangeNotification
                                                  object: musicPlayer];

    [musicPlayer endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
    [musicPlayer stops];
    musicPlayer = nil;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"resetRoom" sender:self];
}
```

Even though im setting it to `nil`, the music continues to play, which tells me its not actually being destroyed.

**EDIT: To be more specific, the second time I instantiate a new copy of `VC2` the following `if` statement is not executing:**

```
- (void) handle_PlaybackStateChanged: (id) notification
{
    MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = [musicPlayer playbackState];

    if(playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped)
        [self getNextSong];

      [self playbackButton];
}
```

I have verified with the debugger that the `playbackState` is `0` both times I instantiate.  However the second time, the `if` statement never happens.

Comment: So are you ever pausing / stopping the player?

Comment: i actually took the code out during testing but yes i originally had `[musicPlayer stop]` in there as well.  it stopped the music...but still doesn't solve the issue of why the new instances are not registering.  also, if it was being set to `nil` shouldn't' it stop if its being released?  I edited my original post also

Comment: What else are you doing when you get the `applicationMusicPlayer`?

Comment: I added some more code...when the song finishes, `getNextSong` retrieves the name of the next song to play from a web API and the media player plays it.  The `playbackButton` function just updates the button to play/pause depending on the state.

Comment: When do you get `applicationMusicPlayer`? Are you starting notifications? Are you auto-starting playback? You show your tear down code but we need to see the setup code too.

Comment: Sorry about that I was trying to keep the code minimal but I omitted too much, updated post.  let me know if you need more or the other notification observers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36605/discussion-between-wain-and-john-hannigan)